# Validate email input field form element

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, react-hook-form

Possible to validate multiple emails seperated by commas with react-hook-form .
So I have a material-ui text field which is uses react-hook-form for the validation..

Initial the input field takes a single email and it's being validated by the react-hook-form.
currently I want the user to be able to enter multiple emails separated by commas and also validates each one of them.
Currently what I'm able to do is validate when the user clicks on submit but ,  I want to be able to validate when the user is typing the emails.

```
<TextField
            onChange={(e) => {
            validateRecipientEmail(e.target.value);
          }}
            name='recipientEmail'
            placeholder='sender@email.com'
            fullWidth
            inputRef={register({
              required: true,
             
            })}
            error={errors.recipientEmail && true}
          />
          {errors.recipientEmail && (
            <Typography variant='caption' className={Type.textError}>
              Invalid email address
            </Typography>
          )}
```

I found a way to kind of achieve the desire goal by doing the validation with onChange event listener.
but after doing the validation and populating the error on the screen. the error disappear when the input field is not focus.

Below is my validation

```
const validateRecipientEmail = (value) => {
let currentEmails = value.split(',').filter((e) => e && e.trim());
let regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]+$/i;
for (let i = 0; i < currentEmails.length; i++) {
  if (!regex.test(currentEmails[i].replace(/\s/g, ''))) {
    setrecipientEmailErrorMessage(
      `Enter valid Email(s) seperated by comma (,)`
    );
    setError('recipientEmail', {
      type: 'manual',
    });
  }
}

if (currentEmails.length > 10) {
  setrecipientEmailErrorMessage(`Emails should not be more than 10`);
  setError('recipientEmail', {
    type: 'manual',
  });
}
  };
```

Comment: did you check with `helperText` and `FormHelperText` https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#helper-text  https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#components

Comment: Thank you but i found a solution that helped

Answer (score 1):

so i found out you can pass a function to validate attribute which solves my problem

```
<TextField
          name='recipientEmail'
          placeholder='Eg. recipient@email.com'
          inputRef={register({
            required: true,
            validate: {
              validEmail: (value) => {
                let currentEmails = value
                  .split(',')
                  .filter((e) => e && e.trim());
                let regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]+$/i;
                for (let i = 0; i < currentEmails.length; i++) {
                  if (!regex.test(currentEmails[i].replace(/\s/g, ''))) {
                    return false;
                  }
                }
              },
              emailLength: (value) => {
                let currentEmails = value
                  .split(',')
                  .filter((e) => e && e.trim());
                if (currentEmails.length > 10) {
                  return false;
                }
              },
            },
          })}
          error={errors.recipientEmail && true}
          fullWidth
        />
```

"validEmail" validate the email and
"emailLength" validate the email length
Thank You